# Line count not working as expected in Unix

Tags: unix

I am trying to get the line count to a variable. The source file filename.dat contains 2 lines of records as:

> 112233;778899
>
> 445566

**Script 1**

```
line_cnt=$(more /home/filename.dat | wc -l)
echo $line_cnt
```

When I run this script, I get the output of 2. Now, I have a modified version:

**Script 2**

```
filename=/home/filename.dat
line_cnt=$(more ${filename} | wc -l)
echo $line_cnt
```

The input file has the same records. But this is giving me an output of 5 even though it has only 2 records.

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Edit - Corrected the file path in 2nd script

Comment: why not filename=/home/filename.dat in script 2?

Comment: Using a pager for that is not a good idea at all? `$(wc -l your_file)` is more than enough. For your question: in your second example, you don't specify a full path. Are you not simply `wc`ing the wrong file?

Comment: To clarify, in the second script, the variable filename=/home/filename.dat

Comment: @Mat to be fair, using the pager will achieve correct results and it results in different output (pager would give just `n`, straight wc -l would give `n filename.dat`).

Comment: @Mat, wc -l /home/filename.dat gives me the count as well as the filename.

Comment: @Rafe: ok, then just use `$(wc -l < the_file)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line_cnt=`cat ${filename} | wc -l`
```

The cat ${filename} | wc -l should be within back quotes.